# Which C++ library is perfect in solving non-linear set of equations with complex roots?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I am developing a small kinetic Monte Carlo code to study atomic evolutions in a material and need to solve several linear and non-linear equations with a high accuracy. My main issue is in finding complex roots of a non-linear equation.
Which C++ library is perfect for solving a non-linear set of equations with complex roots? I am already using Eigen and Ceres in my codes, but it seems that they only can find "real" roots and not "complex" ones. 
All recommendations and ideas are appreciated in advance.

Update-1:

For example, Eigen provides a nonlinear optimization module,
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__NonLinearOptimization__Module.html
which uses (1)Levenberg Marquardt algorithm and (2)Powell hybrid "dogleg" method to find roots and extremums of a nonlinear set of equations. As far as I know, these methods can't find complex roots if any.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific?  Add some equations/links to give a better idea what system you're working with.  Is C++ a hard requirement?

Comment: If this is symbolic, I would recommend Mathematica.  If you're looking for numerical roots, there are a wider array of tools

Comment: For example, I am trying to solve: f(x)=pow(x,2)+x+1; This is a very simple equations with roots, x=-0.5+(sqrt(3)/2)i & x=-0.5-(sqrt(3)/2)i; I need libraries that can numerically (not symbolic) solve this kind of equations (or better to say sets of equations, since I have a very complex mathematical system) in c++ framework.